# Does .net XmlSerializer handle symbols forbidden in xml?

Tags: .net, xml, xml-serialization

does .net XmlSerializer handle forbidden symbols in xml such as `<` or `>` when I serialize an object or I need to handle it myself?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) will automatically XML encode those symbols. Example:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var item = new Item
        {
            Description = "<some description>"
        };
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(item.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, item);
    }
}
```

produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ibm850"?>
<Item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Description>&lt;some description&gt;</Description>
</Item>
```